# AWS provider plugins not getting installed on running terraform init

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

On ruuning terraform init the console shows "Terraform has been successfully initialized!" but in reality none of the providers plugins are installed.
Newbie to terraform here.

I tried running terraform on vs code. Tried to create an EC2 instance with AWS provider. After running terraform init it shows that installation was succesfull but none of the provider plugins were installed, please help.

Comment: How did you verify that? Is anything not working?

Comment: can you please try running `terraform providers` ?

Comment: FYI You have pushed access key & secret key. Hope that doesn't work

Comment: Do you define any providers? For example `provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}`

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti in such cases always flag for moderator attention, they will remove it. I just flagged it now.